# picking first element of list of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of list like this

```
[[('C', '0', 8.625), ('A', '0', 4.5)], [('B', '0', 15.3125), ('D', '2', 6.0625)],
[('C', '1', 8.1875), ('D', '2', 6.0625)], [('G', '2', 11.0625), ('D', '2', 6.0625)],
[('G', '2', 10.1875), ('C', '1', 8.1875)]]
```

How do I check if `('C', '0', 8.625)` is in the list or not (if possible without using loops)?

Comment: that tuple could be anywhere ... I only want to know if it's in the list or not

Comment: What do you mean by "*anywhere*"? Pls Elaborate where exactly `('C', '0', 8.625)` can be... It's not very clear

Comment: how to know that `('x', 'y', z)` is in the list or not?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your intention.

Comment: ok, so if there is a list `[[('1'),('2')],('3')]`, `('x','y','z')` can be at which of `'1'`,`'2'`,`'3'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either perform the membership operation across all the lists by an implicit loop as suggested by @Schoolboy or use itertools.chain

```
>>> some_list = [[('C', '0', 8.625), ('A', '0', 4.5)], [('B', '0', 15.3125), ('D', '2', 6.0625)],
[('C', '1', 8.1875), ('D', '2', 6.0625)], [('G', '2', 11.0625), ('D', '2', 6.0625)],
[('G', '2', 10.1875), ('C', '1', 8.1875)]]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ('C', '0', 8.625) in chain(*some_list)
True
```

Comment: `chain.from_iterable(some_list)` would be better

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your list has 3 "levels", Try this:

```
any(('C', '0', 8.625) in li for li in c)
```

where `c` is your list.